PostGIS index not being used
I am trying to create a database of UK OAs (Output Areas) and their geometry data. There are 180,000 OAs. The max vertice count for a row is 10k. Each record contains either Polygon or MultiPolygon data. My requirement is to query them by coordinates and radius. However my query times are close to a minute and my index is not used.
I am new to GIS so I may have made some mistakes in the setup. For example I wasn't sure whether to choose Geometry or Geography.
Azure Serverless Postgres
PostgreSQL 16.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 11.2.0, 64-bit 
  "POSTGIS=""3.3.3 0"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""160"" GEOS=""3.9.2-CAPI-1.14.3"" PROJ=""9.0.1"" 
   LIBXML=""2.10.4"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.4.1"" 
   WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"""

POSTGIS="3.3.3 0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="160" GEOS="3.9.2-CAPI-1.14.3" 
   PROJ="9.0.1" LIBXML="2.10.4" LIBJSON="0.15" LIBPROTOBUF="1.4.1" 
   WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"

Sample data
  {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 43,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [0.0896434947673892, 51.5399620129335],
            [0.089687377759337, 51.5399341755584],
            [0.0897111145575583, 51.5399193732682],
            [0.0897520693083863, 51.539893850616],
            ...
          ]
        ]
      },
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 44,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [0.0713691928890195, 51.5372534472781],
              [0.0713104459486785, 51.5373234160344],
              ...
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [0.0679683593551999, 51.5361221615334],
              [0.0679641716924609, 51.5361268036861],
              [0.0679127661481493, 51.5361842609525],
              [0.068007410250505, 51.5362482268291],
              [0.0680566436800881, 51.5362795083334],
              ...
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]

My table & index
CREATE TABLE public.output_areas (
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () PRIMARY key,
    oa_code VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    lad_code VARCHAR(12),
    lad_name VARCHAR(255),
    area DOUBLE PRECISION,
    length DOUBLE PRECISION,
    geography geography (geometry, 4326)
);

CREATE index output_areas_geography_idx ON public.output_areas USING gist (geography);

My insert statement
INSERT INTO public.output_areas (id, oa_code, lad_code, lad_name, area, length, geography)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($7), 4326))

My select statement
SELECT *
FROM public.output_areas
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geography,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.09, 51.505), 4326)::geography,
    500,
    true
);

Explain
Gather  (cost=1000.00..1984792.83 rows=18 width=5385)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on output_areas  (cost=0.00..1983791.03 rows=8 width=5385)
"        Filter: st_dwithin((geography)::geography, '0101000020E61000000AD7A3703D0AB7BF713D0AD7A3C04940'::geography, '500'::double precision, true)"

That query takes 59s to return 27 rows.
What am I doing wrong?

@Zegarek Sorry for the confusion. Yes 180,000 is OAs (rows in the table). Each has a number of vertices.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Clarification: what's the select version(), postgis_full_version();? It's weird that it works with st_intersects() but not with st_dwithin(). What if you manually replace the condition?select * from output_areas where (output_areas.geography && _st_expand('0101000020E61000000AD7A3703D0AB7BF713D0AD7A3C04940'::geography, '500'::double precision)) and 500<=st_distance(output_areas.geography, '0101000020E61000000AD7A3703D0AB7BF713D0AD7A3C04940'::geography, true);

I answered in the chat. Thanks so much everyone so far for the help.

Please use the chat room for further discussion
